# Java Reg Expression Excluding (Non word Character)

Tags: java, regex, expression

Hi I am new to reg expressions and I am trying to rename complicated file names like this one below:

```
3-M-COLORADOW-22017DB-LABEL
```

I want to rename this file name to this using java reg expressions:

```
3-M-COLORADOW-LABEL
```

However with my current beginning knowledge of Java Reg expressions I have only gotten this far:

[image]

I have tried many combinations with no success.I just need help finding the right combination of java reg expressions to achieve my goal. Basically i am trying to take one of the (dashes out). Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
    for(File file:filesInDir) {
        //x++;
        String name = file.getName();
        String newName = name;
        String sameName = name;
        if (name.contains("LABEL")){
           newName = sameName.replaceAll("(.*)-(.*)(-LABEL)", "$1$3") ; 
           System.out.println(newName); // prints prints to file 
           String newPath = absolutePathOne + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath)); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replaceAll with groups like this :

```
String str = "3-M-COLORADOW-22017DB-LABEL".replaceAll("(.*)-(.*)(-LABEL)", "$1$3");
```

Output

```
3-M-COLORADOW-LABEL
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7dS77/1)

Comment: Sorry will post it above

Comment: can you please edit your question @JonathanHofler the code in comment is not readable!

Comment: I posted my code above with one of the solutions given.

Comment: @JonathanHofler you don't need to use `String sameName = name;` you can use just `name`

Comment: and you have to try your solution it seems correct @JonathanHofler

Comment: Okay I will change that

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give much information about the structure of your filenames, i'll assume you want to filter out numbers followed by letters. You could use the following regex:

```
(.*)-\d+\D+(-.*) // java-syntax: "(.*)-\\d+\\D+(-.*)"
```

with a `Matcher`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)-\\d+\\D+(-.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(oldFilename);
if (matcher.matches) {
    String newFilename = m.group(1) + m.group(2);
}
```